# Getting the same REQUEST_FILENAME for different REQUEST_URI

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Having an odd issue with mod_rewrite.

A URI like `/news` will match correctly since `news.php` exists. However, `/news/1900-01-01/title` will match as if it was `/news`!

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$ #workaround for URIs ending in a slash passing the previous check
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ debug.php?page=$1.php&req_filename=%{REQUEST_FILENAME}&req_uri=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

If run with `/news` it produces the expected result:

```
page=/news.php
req_filename=/home/domain/public_html/news
req_uri=/news
```

If run with `/news/1900-01-01/title` it produces:

```
page=/news/1900-01-01/title.php
req_filename=/home/domain/public_html/news
req_uri=/news/1900-01-01/title
```

Why is `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` the same for both?

I already have a work-around for the news items; moved `RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ news-item.php?date=$1&title=$2 [L]` above this snippet. However, I would like to understand how 2 unique URIs can resolve to the same non-existant (script adds the .php) file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache tries to find the lowest "real" directory, then processes the directives corresponding to that directory (e.g. .htaccess or other dir-specific directives). In your case, I presume the URI doesn't correspond to any real directory. Apache then uses Content Negotiation, and if Multiviews is set (which I suspect it is in your case) then it finds the best match based on the filename. Since you have a news.php, that's what it matches. If you want to learn more you can look up pages explaining the keywords Content Negotiation and Multivews.

Comment: Thank you. That isn't clear in the documentation. I'm not sure of the full server configuration. The client's website is on a shared hosting server.